# How to query an elasticsearch join field name?

Tags: elasticsearch, join, parent

Say I have a parent document with the following structure:

```
{
   "join": {
       "name": "parent"
   }
   "foo": 3
}
```

How could I query all documents where the join name is `parent`?

I have tried the naive approach:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term": { "join.name" : "parent" }
    }
}
```

But it returns 0 results. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide mappings for your index? This is hard to parse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to append `.name` to the `join` field.

```
GET my-index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term": { "join" : "parent" }
    }
}
```